# reading from table column checking multiple columns on a diff trable

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working in oracle and trying to come up with a statement that reads column Id from TableA and checks 3 different columns in TableB. For Example,

[image]

[image: tableA]

I am trying to write a sql statement in which it looks in TableA for Column "Id" in this case which is "1" and sees if it is in one the three id columns (id1, id2, id3) in TableB and return the Name from Table B. I thought about transposing table B as well as thinnking if ican just do a join and have "or" instead of "AND" on the inner join On part.

Comment: Have you tried using `OR` yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `in` or `or` for a `join` condition:

```
select a.*, b.*
from a join
     b
     on a.id in (b.id1, b.id2, b.id3);
```